# Issue running php laravel application - Google App Engine

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an web application with PHP Laravel frontend and Postgress SQL backend. I have deployed this application to google app engine flex environment. After deployment to app engine, getting following error after login from the site. The application runs fine on my local environment after login when pointed the database to google cloud SQL postgress database.

```
 Error:   
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
    in 57369c716dc79e4b8bf3c1b292b0f7eb440a33da.php line 35
    at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable', '/app/storage/framework/views/57369c716dc79e4b8bf3c1b292b0f7eb440a33da.php', '35', array('__path' => '/app/storage/framework/views/57369c716dc79e4b8bf3c1b292b0f7eb440a33da.php', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'obLevel' => '2', 'data' => object(stdClass)), 'obLevel' => '3', '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'data' => object(stdClass))) in 57369c716dc79e4b8bf3c1b292b0f7eb440a33da.php line 35
```

Here is my app.yaml file

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public


skip_files:
  - .env   


env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
  DB_DRIVER: 'pgsql'
  DB_CONNECTION: pgsql
  DB_HOST: <ipaddress of cloud sql db>
  DB_PORT: 5432
  DB_DATABASE: dbname
  DB_USERNAME: xxxxxxx
  DB_PASSWORD: xxyyzz
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/xxx:xyz:yxz"
  REDIS_HOST: localhost
  REDIS_PASSWORD : null
  REDIS_PORT: 6379

beta_settings: 
  cloud_sql_instances: "xyz:xyzz:instance=tcp:5432"
```

Comment: It might be that you have copied some files from your local dev environment and you just need to clear the views and cache with `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`. If you can't run the console commands, then just delete all files inside `storage/framework/views/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error sounds awfully like Google App Engine is running PHP 7.2+ and your code is incompatible with it. 7.2 introduced some changes to the semantics of the `count()` function so look into this change and specifically at your own uses of the function to confirm it's being used correctly.